# What's the best way to implement a semaphore in Go

Tags: go, semaphore

I have a test program where I want to run multiple copies of the program from the command-line, and I need to know the first instance of the program to start. In Dart, I do the following which someone suggested to me :

```
RawServerSocket.bind("127.0.0.1", 8087)
```

If that fails, then I know that another program has "locked" the port. That solves the problem sufficiently well for me. The lock is released when the program terminates or when the socket is explicitly closed.

How can I achieve a similar result in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say which platform you are using.  If you want to be cross platform then the solution of opening a local socket is very easy.  Here is how you do it in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9876")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to get lock: ", err)
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    log.Print("Started")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
    log.Print("Ending")
}
```

A cross platform way of doing this without using a socket is quite hard unfortunately and would involve two sets of code one for Unix like systems and one for windows.

Note that virus checkers don't like programs opening listening sockets on windows...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I want cross-platform and ideally memory-based solution (not file). Two sets of code would be OK (I think). A global object that can be closed/released is essential. As far as virus-checkers, I guess I'll have to cross that bridge. I specifically avoided the file-based solution, but if all else fails ... I'll try your solution, but it sounds as though it's not cross-platform.

Comment: The solution above will work on all Go supported platforms win/mac/linux/freebsd/etc. It may cause a popup on windows av which can be allowed once and won't bother you again...

Answer (score 3):

The 'unix way' would be to create a pid file within /var/run/<name>.pid
This is how we do it with Docker https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/docker/docker.go#L91
If the file exists, then it means the program is already started.

I would not recommend to use the bind method, it lock a port for nothing and you can't be sure that an other program is not using the port.

Comment: I don't think locking a port is a problem - certainly not in a test environment. The problem of clashes can be solved by the program having a default port to lock but checking for an environment variable to override the default. Using a file as you suggest is probably Ok also, but it just doesn't appeal to me.

Answer (score 2):

What about using `os.OpenFile()` with `os.CREATE | os.O_EXCL` flag?

```
file, err := os.OpenFile("lock", os.O_CREATE | os.O_EXCL | os.O_RDWR, 0400)
if err != nil {
        // Someone else has acquired the lock.
}
defer file.Close()
defer os.Remove("lock") // Ignoring errors here!
```

I haven't compiler or tested this, but it should work and in any case, you get the idea...

Comment: Of course if your program dies somehow without removing the file, you have a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `github.com/gofrs/flock` package, using code something like this for your purposes:

```
import "github.com/gofrs/flock"

fileLock := flock.New("/var/lock/go-lock.lock")

locked, err := fileLock.TryLock()

if err != nil {
    // handle locking error
}

if locked {
    // handle "first one in" case
    fileLock.Unlock()
} else {
    // handle subsequent cases
}
```

For more info see https://github.com/gofrs/flock .